# Facebook API v2.0 breakdowns

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

As facebook upgrades to v2.0 and making most of the data confidential now, how can i get user details like `username, userid` (Not `app-scoped ID`)

Any help would be highly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `username` and real `user_id` will no longer be returned by the Graph API 2.0, as either would reveal the user's real profile. The only way to determine who the user is now is to follow the new `link` in the data:

`https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxx/`

This is mainly done to prevent certain developers from sharing user_ids with third-party apps and ad networks.